Test In-App Purchase on Simulator -> Error
Not able to see storeProducts on ios app.
Simulator:
Iphone 15 pro max (ios 17.0+)
Environment/Tech Stack
In-App Purchase
Xcode
App Store Connect
RevenueCat
After adding the storekit configuration file and syncing it with app store connect, I have also saved the certificate file to save the reciepts.
Moreover, I also double/triple checked if the product IDs are matching on app store connect + storekit config file + revenue cat and yes they do.
Error:
[d9e4_SK1] Finished product request with error Error Domain=ASDErrorDomain Code=511 "(null)"
ERROR: ‼️ Store products request failed! Error: Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "An unknown error occurred" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error occurred, NSUnderlyingError=0x30287d8c0 {Error Domain=ASDErrorDomain Code=511 "(null)"}}
I have searched throughout the internet, however, I do not understand what is the meaning of code 511.
Would be happy to have any hints.
I tried the following:

product IDs are same on all the parties: App Store Connect, storekit config file, Revenue Cat
stored the certificate file from xcode
Network issues : none
Tested on hardware directly.


okay, this was the reason.
This was my workflow

signed paid apps agreement
add new subscriptions
test the app

This is wrong and subscriptions will not show up correctly.
This has to be the workflow

sign paid apps agreement
fill both the tax forms
provide bank account details
add new subscriptions -> this has to be done after all the formalities
test the app

Then the subscriptions will be shown correctly.
It is no point just trying to get the old subscriptions show up by refreshing multipe times, one really needs to add new subscriptions after finishing all the app store connect formalities and only then it works.
